# Highlight all matching strings/substrings on a datagrid from a keyword search

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, visual-studio-2003

Can someone help me on how to highlight the matching strings/substrings from a keyword search?

For example if the user inputs "BEARING", the datagrid should display the following

ADAPTER **BEARING**

BAR AIR**BEARING** TURN

**BEARING** BALL

**BEARING** BRONZE

I am almost finish but in this example, the whole AIRBEARING is highlighted which supposed to be, it is only the BEARING that should be highlighted only.

Comment: in my example above AIR*BEARING* should be AIR<b>BEARING</b>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highlight a list of words using a regular expression in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653700/highlight-a-list-of-words-using-a-regular-expression-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a css class and call it 'highlight':

```
.highlight { background-color: yellow; }
```

Then use a regex replace to wrap that text with the class:

```
function highlight(walloftext, valuetohighlight) {
    var x = new RegExp("(" + valuetohighlight + ")", "gi");
    return walloftext.replace(x, '<span class="highlight">$1</span>');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/5cCuc/