# Find and replace several words without affecting future replacements

Tags: c#

What I want to do is some kind of "banned words" highlighting.

Here are the values I have :

I have a list of bannedwords in an array

```
{ "word1", "word2", "word3", "word4" }
```

I have a string representing a comment

```
"i want to word1ban this word3 stupidword4 comment"
```

I want to highlight these within html bold tags (`<b> </b>`).
So for example, this comment string would become :

```
"i want to <b>word1</b>ban this <b>word3</b> stupid<b>word4</b> comment"
```

The way I do this actually, is using a regex replacement and it works pretty well except for one thing which is annoying for me.

```
foreach (var word in words)
{
    value = Regex.Replace(value, string.Format(@"{0}", Regex.Escape(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(word))), "<b>" + word + "</b>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

The problem with this, and it also depends of the order of the words in the array, is if one of the banned words will affect your replacement (`<b>` or `</b>`)

For example, if you add this to the banned words : `<b`

Following the code, the first iteration result will be :

```
"i want to <b>word1</b>ban this <b>word3</b> stupid<b>word4</b> comment"
```

Then replacing with `<b` after it will be :

```
"i want to <b><b</b>>word1</b>ban this <b><b</b>>word3</b> stupid<b><b</b>>word4</b> comment"
```

I don't want to affect my replacement. I'm wondering how we can do this. I tried adding exceptions to my regex to exclude `<b>` and `</b>` in the replacement without success.

Comment: Your replacement knows nothing of HTML it's just replacing what you tell it to. It can't tell the difference between text and text within a tag. You need to make your replacement regex more explicit, or use something like HTML Agility Pack which can parse the HTML.

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653700/highlight-a-list-of-words-using-a-regular-expression-in-c-sharp

Comment: You can always use regex on elements of parsed HTML and avoid breaking tags that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the whole "HTML" aspect of the problem, and just coming at it from the angle of

> I want to find and replace several words, but I don't want a replacement I've made to affect future replacements

you can do one thing: make all the replacements at once!

```
var pattern = "(" + String.Join("|", words.Select(w => Regex.Escape(w))) + ")";
// e.g. (word1|word2|word3|word4)
value = Regex.Replace(
    value,
    pattern,
    "<b>$1</b>",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Yes, I wanted a solution that would, as you say, be "ignoring" the HTML aspect, this was just for the problem context. Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for and it works very well !

Answer (score 0):

In the general case what you need here is to replace some terms in the input but not in the output that has been produced so far. That's not too hard to do manually, but first you will have to determine which term gets priority to be replaced.

Let's say that you have a dictionary of terms and replacements, and the strategy for choosing which term to replace is "replace the one that appears closest to the start of the input; if many terms appear at the same position, replace the longest one". Here's one way to do that:

```
string ReplaceWithoutOverlap(string input, IDictionary<string, string> replacements)
{
    var processedCharCount = 0;
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (processedCharCount < input.Length) {
        var replacement = replacements
                .Select(r => Tuple.Create(r.Key, input.IndexOf(r.Key, processedCharCount)))
                .Where(t => t.Item2 != -1)
                .OrderBy(t => t.Item2)
                .ThenByDescending(t => t.Item1.Length)
                .FirstOrDefault();

        if (replacement == null)
        {
            break;
        }

        sb.Append(input, processedCharCount, replacement.Item2 - processedCharCount);
        sb.Append(replacements[replacement.Item1]);
        processedCharCount = replacement.Item2 + replacement.Item1.Length;
    }

    sb.Append(input.Substring(processedCharCount));
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/H98GiS)**.

Of course this is not *exactly* what you want to do here (in fact replacing everything at once with one regex is probably the most convenient), but you can see how it would work.